# Equal Method: Comparing 2 Objects

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I am currently working on a project in java. I need to create a method that compares two items by name. My first file is called `Item` which has a name. The second file has an `arrayList` of `Items`. I need to create an equal method which compares two items based on their name. I need to return a `boolean` and the code starts with this.

```
public boolean toEqual(Object o)
```

I am confused about what to do next. I know you will probably have to use an if else statement as well as the `getName()` method I created. However I think am supposed to cast the object as an Item object but I don't know how. Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct on what to do, and so now you just need to put it together.

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting  That site has some info on casting objects in Java.  Basically to case one object to another, you do something like this:

```
Item i = (Item) o;
```

That will cast your `o` to type `Item`

Next you need to see if `i.getName().equals(getName())`.  You can return that result and you should be done :)

Good luck!

Comment: Isn't it the case that `i.getName() == getName()` will do a reference comparison, not a content comparison? Assuming that name is a `String` type or a non-primititve type, shouldn't you be using `i.getName().equals(getName())`?

Comment: @blahman You're right.  Updated.  I forgot mid-sentence that this was Java and not C#

Answer (score 1):

You can cast object like this -

```
(ClassName)obj
```

However, a much better approach would be to override equals & hashcode methods of java.lang.Object and handle it there. To know how to override it correctly, you can refer to this article - 
http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html

HTH,
- Manish

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `boolean equals(Object)` and `int hashCode()` for the item class, because then you can simply invoke the contains(Object) method of the list to find if a matching item exists in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class called `Item`
And your `Item` class have an instance field called `name` which you use it to store the name of the item.

```
class Item {
    private String name = "item name";

    public String getName() {
        return name
    }

    public boolean toEqual(Object o) {
        // Firstly cast it to Item
        Item item = (Item) o;
        // Then perform the compare
        return (name.equals(item.getName()));
    }
}
```

Actually you can change the signature of `toEqual` method to 
`public boolean toEqual(Item o)`. In this case you will not need the cast operation.

```
public boolean toEqual(Item o) {
    // Perform the compare
    return (name.equals(o.getName()));
}
```